# Website link shows Apache HTTP Server Documentation

Tags: apache, centos

My website directory /manual shows **Apache HTTP Server Version 2.2 Documentation** page i have removed this directory from my FTP but still o a, getting this.

I am using Linux Centos bellow is my manual.conf file configuration

There is a manual.conf which shows bellow configurations

```
#
# This configuration file allows the manual to be accessed at
# http://localhost/manual/
#
AliasMatch ^/manual(?:/(?:de|en|fr|ja|ko|ru))?(/.*)?$ "/var/www/manual$1"

<Directory "/var/www/manual">
    Options Indexes
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to remove that link from your server configuration. If you have done this you need also to restart your apache server.

To remove the documentation look into your apache configuration (on Debian e.g. `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default`) for a block like this one here:

```
Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
   ...
</Directory>
```

And comment them with `#` out. Than don't forget to restart the apache server to commit the changes.

---

After your update you seems to have two options:

1. Delete the whole file. That should remove the link for ever.
2. Comment all that lines out by adding a `#` to the beginning of all lines. This is for some cases better if you want to recover the manual in the future.

And restart the server with:

```
service httpd graceful
```

Comment: From Which configuration of my server.

Comment: I am usin linux centos then what it will be.

Comment: Maybe somewhere around `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`. See also the [centos wiki](http://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/ApacheVhostDir). rtfm :)

Comment: my problem has been fixed by commenting this.

Answer (score 0):

In fedora

```
dnf remove httpd-manual.noarch
service httpd restart
```

Answer (score 0):

If you still have this behaviour and want to correct it just disable the apache2-doc conf and restart the apache2 service. `a2disconf apache2-doc`.